# auto_increment countdown on MariaDB

Tags: performance, mariadb, auto-increment

I have a DB where every day I add 300 register of the sale information (total more than 100,000 and incremented). Just de last sales information is relevant. The query is like this:

```
SELECT a.ID, a.amount, a.product, a.date, b.status FROM sales AS a
LEFT JOIN status as b ON a.id = b.id_sales AND b.status = '1'
WHERE a.store LIKE '%A%'
ORDER BY a.ID desc
LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0;
```

You can see the query show you all sales from the store A in status 1 (payed), but always show the first was added (the most old), is necessary added "ORDER BY ID desc" to see the newest. But by adding the "ORDER BY" the query takes 20 times longer. I believe that a good solution is to order the table in reverse (auto_decrement) when entering the records, so that when performing the query it shows the newest records. Is it possible to do that? Or what do you recommend me to do so that I don't spend too many resources, and it doesn't take so long to sort the entire table to show me the newest ones.

The EXPLAIN show this:

> id;select_type;table;type;possible_keys;key;key_len;ref;rows;Extra
> 1;SIMPLE;a;ALL;\N;\N;\N;\N;97662;Using where; Using temporary; Using
> filesort 1;SIMPLE;b;ALL;\N;\N;\N;\N;1270;Using where; Using join buffer
> (flat, BNL join)

id as the primary key in both tables

-------------------------------  Edit  ---------------------------

I added a left join in the query that I had removed thinking it wasn't part of the problem.
Add the explain result

Comment: Hmm, you can try an index on `(id DESC, store, amount, product, date)`. It would also help not use a wildcard at the beginning of the matching string for `LIKE`. If that's possible an index on `(store, id DESC, amount, product, date)` might be the one you search for.

Comment: Did you analyze the statement with `EXPLAIN` ? If yes, please post the result (and if possible also the table definition)

Comment: I edited and response you both